# SSH node with password does not work RUDECK

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying to configure an SSH node authenticating with password, but it doesn't work.

My file is this .xml is like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yP8X.png
Obs:Node's ssh port is 2222

Node's default configuration
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj4eB.png

Comment: I don't think it's enough to point the password storage path to a directory in the XML, afaik it needs to point to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ssh-password-storage-path` attribute needs a valid rundeck key storage password entry, something like `keys/mypassword/password`. Currently is pointing to a Rundeck key storage folder, no a password entry.

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-password-storage).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made this configuration, but it still doesn't work.

do i need to create the .password file and put a password inside the file?

Comment: you need to put the password file in that key storage entry (take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/system-configs.html#key-storage)